# I Can Be Two Different Things, Literally

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

Haven't seen a Riley in a while so I decided to make one

> > **RIDDLE**
>
> My prefix is a program
>
> But it is also a software
>
> My infix is found in almost everywhere
>
> Although it is also the name of a corporation in the US
>
> Change one letter in my suffix
>
> And you will end up where you currently are
>
> My whole can be two very different things

Hint 1 :

> *The Word* is very useful but it can also be eaten

Comment: does program mean TV shows or computer programming?

Comment: All I can say is that it has no relation whatsoever with TV shows

Comment: Is the prefix `Jam`?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Nope :D

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid Oops, forgot to tag you. Sorry :D

Comment: Is the prefix a programming language?

Comment: Is the word an auto-antonym?

Comment: @Duck Well that could be correct, I don't know :D

Comment: @Duck No, it's not an auto-antonym

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A second bite at the core of this

> apple

My prefix is a program, But it is also a software

> **app** - a computer program

My infix is found almost everywhere, Although it is also the name of a corporation in the US

> **ppl** - abbreviation for people, and PPL is the US stock symbol for the large energy company PPL Corp (formerly Pennsylvania Power and Light).

Change one letter in my suffix and you will end up where you currently are

> **ple** - changes to PSE

My whole can be two very different things

> The technology company or the fruit.

Comment: I was thinking this from the infix clue but couldn't think of anything to go infront of or behind it ><

Comment: @AHKieran - same too, and the infix being the word may be forbidden.

Comment: Everything is correct except for the infix

Comment: @KevinL,thanks and included a more fitting infix now.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Bravo! Will accept tomorrow :D